# Contribution Summary can't be filtered by payment method

Tags: drupal, 4.6

I wonder why Contribution Summaries can be filtered on pretty much everything but not on the payment method, even though payment method (check, bank, cash...) is a mandatory input...
Do I miss something and there is a way to do it?

Comment: I now found this: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-report

Comment: But I am still happy if someone has some tips to share.

Comment: The short answer is that no one must have needed this before - because it'd be very easy to add.  Instead of writing an extension/custom report, I'd honestly just add this to the core report (could be done with 3-5 lines of code) and submit the improvement to core CiviCRM for inclusion in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the Contribution **Details** Report rather than the **Summary** Report.  In the "Columns" tab, choose "Payment Type".  In the "Sorting Tab" select "Choose a Payment Method" as the sorting method, plus any other columns you wish to sort by.

Hope this helps.